# Pandas Dataframe Regrouping

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe, it shows the coordinate where there is a step in a tower, including z-min, and z-max:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

names = ['T1', 'T2', 'T2', 'T1', 'T1']
coord = [0, 0, 5, 50, 70]


df = pd.DataFrame([names , coord ], index=['Name', 'Cord']).T
```

Resulting in:

```
  Name Cord
0    T1   0
1    T2   0
2    T2   5
3    T1   50
4    T1   70
```

For every **unique** coordinate, I would like to regroup all towers whose z-max is smaller or equal to that coordinate. Hence:

```
     Name      Cord
0    T1,T2      0
1    T1,T2      5
2    T1         50
3    T1         70
```

How can I do that?

### What I have done so far

group by unique coordinate:

```
import numpy as np

g = df.groupby('Cord')['Name'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x)))
```

I get:

```
Cord
0     [T1, T2]
5         [T2]
50        [T1]
70        [T1]
```

... but for the rest, I am not sure.

### Edit

The proposed answer does not work for the special case that the z-mins of the two towers are not the same:

```
import pandas as pd

names = ['T1', 'T2', 'T2', 'T1', 'T1']
coord = [0, 5, 10, 50, 70]


df = pd.DataFrame([names , coord ], index=['Name', 'Cord']).T
```

Comment: Why is it `T1, T2` at `50` but only `T1` at `70`?

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try pivotting:

```
(df.pivot(index='Cord', columns='Name', values='Name')
   .bfill().apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna()), axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
Cord
0     [T1, T2]
5     [T1, T2]
50        [T1]
70        [T1]
dtype: object
```

---

**Explanation**: First we pivot the table so it looks similar to your picture:

```
df.pivot(index='Cord', columns='Name', values='Name')
```

which gives:

```
Name   T1   T2
Cord          
0      T1   T2
5     NaN   T2
50     T1  NaN
70     T1  NaN
```

So you can see the *towers* at all `Cord` levels, except that they are bottom-up. Now we use `bfill` to fill the missing intermediate levels, e.g. `5` on `T1`.

Finally, we want to aggregate along the rows, which means `apply` with `axis=1`. The lambda function is self-explained (I hope).

---

**Update**: for the updated data, we need to `bfill` from the first non-nan values:

```
(df.pivot(index='Cord', columns='Name', values='Name')
   .apply(lambda x: x[x.notna().cumsum().ne(0)].bfill())
   .apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna()), axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
Cord
0         [T1]
5     [T1, T2]
10    [T1, T2]
50        [T1]
70        [T1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty impressive. Could you briefly outline in your response what the code is doing? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I updated my question: Do you think you could have another look at it? Thanks!